# Enviar pdf por email desde android

Tags: android-studio, email

Tengo una app que me permite realizar el envió de un pdf por correo electrónico sea hotmail o gmail.
Cuando hice la app la realice toda en actividades y aun funciona correctamente pero ahora decidí crear una versión en Fragments y el método para enviar los pdf dejo de funcionar.

dejare el codigo a continuacion

**Metodo en el Fragment FragmentoVentas**

**sqLiteDb.vecFact[5]:** Correo del que envia
**edtEmail.getText().toString():** Correo al que envio
**sqLiteDb.vecFact[6]:** Contraseña del correo que envia
**archivo:** ruta del pdf

```
  private void enviarPdf(String archivo){ //archivo es la ruta del pdf que esta en el dispositivo y que se creo 
    TareaAsincronaEmail tMail = new TareaAsincronaEmail(getActivity(),"envio");
    tMail.execute(sqLiteDb.vecFact[5],edtEmail.getText().toString(),sqLiteDb.vecFact[6],archivo);
    try {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),tMail.get(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Tarea asincrona Mail**

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port","587");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", params[0]);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(true);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(params[0]));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(params[1]));
            message.setSubject("Factura...");
            message.setText("Se le hace envio de su factura"); //el Logcat me marca el error en esta linea

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPartAdjunto = new MimeBodyPart();
            mimeBodyPartAdjunto.setFileName("Factura_de_venta_sistevar.pdf");
            mimeBodyPartAdjunto.attachFile(params[3]);
            multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPartAdjunto);

            message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(params[0]));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(params[1]));
            message.setSubject("Gracias por comprar en sistevar");
            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
            t.connect(params[0],params[2]);
            t.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
            t.close();
            return "Mensaje enviado";
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Error que marca el Logcat**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.activation.DataHandler" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

**Todo este codigo es el mismo que uso en la app donde funciona en actividades pero en este que es con fragmentos se cuelga al momento de enviar el correo.**

Answer (score -1):

Si revisas el error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "javax.activation.DataHandler" on path:

indica que estas usando en tu proyecto una clase de `javax` llamada [DataHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/DataHandler.html) , usar las clases de `javax` en Android no es soportado ya que no estan incluidas en la Android library, por esa razón la clase no existe y estas obteniendo este error.

---

Investigando un poco más de tu error encontré esta [pregunta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368704/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-activation-datahandler-in-android), donde indica que uso [**Javamail**](https://code.google.com/archive/p/javamail-android/) para su objetivo.

> Hay tres bibliotecas que debe incluir en su aplicación: `mail.jar`,
>   `activation.jar` y  `additionnal.jar` (sic). Parece que le falta algo
>   de lo que depende la biblioteca de activación, y esto podría deberse a
>   que no está utilizando el puerto Android de esta biblioteca. He
>   utilizado con éxito la versión de `javamail` para `Android` en un
>   proyecto y funciona muy bien.